# Google maps connecting markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gps

I have hundreds of GPS coordinates (collected by a GPS module in my car) in my database and I am loading them to google maps. Is there some way I can connect these coordinates in same way as google waypoints do (so the connecting line always stays on a road)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would probably want to use the [Google Directions Web Service API.](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/) You would use something like PHP or Python to do a call between each of the points and then cache the directions on your server. Then serve them out as Polylines on your map. Or you could do it client side, in the browser, using the [Directions Service](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/directions.html).

Comment: So if I want to show couple of hundreds points I have to send every pair of coordinates to google server? Isn't there some other way?

Comment: Not through the Google Maps API, no. You can render the lines directly, but not following the road.