# Android map based location

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, geolocation

I use gps for my android app to get the user's current location. Since gps locations is very inaccurate in some terrains (e.g. forest), I want to use map information to calculate a better location estimation, for example by assuming the user won't leave roads.

Is there a way to evaluate a map (google map or any) based on gps lat./long. and find nearby roads, distance to neabry roads?

I do no need full code, just keywords, links to instructions, tutorials, etc.

Comment: This has to be possible, it is what most navigation applications do in order to calculate routes (navigation through roads). Looks as though you are going to have to pull the directions using outside languages in unison with Google Directions Web Service API. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9169169/google-maps-connecting-markers

Answer (score 0):

Geofencing feature [Location API](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html) is the best if you want to detect special places check it maybe helpful.